# How to implement an echo-service over bluetooth smart

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to find examples of how to implement a service over bluetooth smart (ble). I would prefer a python implementation. The step i'm most interested in is the bindning between ble and the application that are going to respond. So an implementation of Echo seems like the perfect match for solving my problem.